# xmbc Player onPlayBackEnded not being called

Tags: python, kodi

I am having an issue where I've implemented a class to listen when onPlayBackEnded has ended, but it does not appear to be firing. This is my code:

http://mirrors.kodi.tv/docs/python-docs/13.0-gotham/xbmc.html#Player-onPlayBackEnded

```
class BWPlayer(xbmc.Player) :

    def __init__ (self):
        xbmc.Player.__init__(self)

    def onPlayBackStarted(self):
         print("Strted") 

    def onPlayBackEnded(self):

        xbmcgui.Dialog().ok(addonname, "Done Playing")

    def onPlayBackStopped(self):
         print("Strted") 

    def onPlayBackPaused(self):
         print("Strted") 

    def onPlayBackResumed(self):
         print("Strted")

player      = BWPlayer()
player.play(item='file.mp4')
```

Did I implement something wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

'player.play' is not a blocking call which means that your script will continue to run to the very end, and then your `player` instance goes out of scope and is garbage-collected.

You need to create some kine of long-running loop to prevent your script from exiting. Something like this:

```
player.play(item='file.mp4')
xbmc.sleep(500)  # Wait until playback starts
while player.isPlaying():
    xbmc.sleep(500)
```

If you need your script to run forever (until Kodi exits) then you will need something like this:

```
monitor = xbmc.Monitor()
monitor.waitForAbort()
```

`monitor.waitForAbort()` will block your script and prevent it from exiting while Kodi is running.

Comment: Thank! One question that I have not ben about to find, is xbmc.sleep milliseconds, seconds, or minutes?

Comment: Milliseconds with 100ms minimal duration.